# webrtc ice_server never registeres as ice candidate

Tags: javascript, webrtc, stun, turn

I am building a webrtc client where i am using a turn and stun server. This is working if i am turning of the firewall. When i breakpoint the on ice candidate function i see that my ice servers are not added as ICE candidate.

This is the code:

```
var rtc_configuration =
    {
        iceServers: [
            {urls: "stun:numb.viagenie.ca"},
            {urls: "turn:numb.viagenie.ca", username: "username", credential: "credential", credentialType: "password"}
        ],
        bundlePolicy: "balanced",
        iceTransportPolicy: "all",
        rtcpMuxPolicy: "negotiate",
        iceCandidatePoolSize: 20,
        certificates: []
    };
    var peer_connection = new rtc_peer_connection(rtc_configuration);
    peer_connection.onicecandidate = pc_on_ice_candidate;
```

but when i breakpoint on the onicecandidate funtion, only the default candidates are added, and not the ice servers that are in the configuration.
I am using the last version of firefox.

Does anybody have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is because TURN server transport type is UDP, and thanks to the firewall, the UDP ports would be blocked, hence no ICE candidates, try adding TURN credentials with TCP transport mode...